# Biber produces empty bbl file

Tags: biblatex, biber, output, bbl

I always wanted to switch from BibTeX to BibLaTeX, so I thought I'd give it a try today. After some reading on the manual, I eventually managed to convert all commands to the new syntax. Neither pdfLaTeX nor Biber give any errors, however the bbl file is empty and I receive warnings about undefined references and empty bibliographies. I have read many similar problems in this forum, however none of them solved my case. Since the BibLaTeX documentation is one of the few package documentations I have not read completely, I assume i'm naively doing something wrong.
My tex file:

```
\documentclass[fontsize = 11pt,paper = a4,ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman,british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{OLED}.
\end{document}
```

test.bib:

```
@Book{OLED,
    author = {Hari Singh Nalwa and Lauren Shea Rohwer},
    title = {Organic Light-Emitting Diodes},
    series = {Handbook of Luminescence, Display Materials and Devices},
    year = {2003},
    publisher = {American Scientific Publishers}
}
```

Biber gives a version warning in the blg file, even though BibLaTeX 3.0 is installed:

```
[0] Config.pm:324> INFO - This is Biber 2.1
[0] Config.pm:327> INFO - Logfile is 'Test.blg'
[52] biber-MSWIN:273> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[52] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'Test.bcf'
[245] Utils.pm:146> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.6, expected version 2.7
[246] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[262] Biber.pm:2977> INFO - Processing section 0
[282] Biber.pm:3115> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test.bib' for section 0
[286] bibtex.pm:1021> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[287] bibtex.pm:895> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'
```

Comment: Your biblatex is too old. Check in the log-file which version is used and where it is located.

Comment: It was indeed the biblatex version. Very unhappy with how MikTex behaves when you press the 'update' button

Comment: I have never had a problem with updates. Maybe you have a problem with User mode and Admin mode? (Biber is installed in User mode and `biblatex` in Admin mode or vice versa. Or you haven't installed Biber via the Package Manager at all.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update, it was caused by a version mismatch between `biblatex` and Biber.