# Biber generates empty bbl file

Tags: biblatex

my Biber don't creates the `bbl` file anymore. One week before everything worked just fine. I tried to install a fresh TeXLive (2020) distro on my laptop, but it doesn't work either.

With TeXLive 2019 (which was installed on my laptop) it doesn't work either (error: `ifluatex.sty not found`). If I put the file manually in the folder the output is the same as with TeXLive 2020.

I've already reviewed this posts and tried the solutions (spoiler: they're not working):

- [biber generates empty bbl-file [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558846/biber-generates-empty-bbl-file)
- [Problem with biber: file.bcf is malformed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363934/problem-with-biber-file-bcf-is-malformed)
- [biber generate empty bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378495/biber-generate-empty-bbl-file)
- [The bbl file is not generated and still malformed file bcf even if I still use \addbibresource{file.bib} in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464593/the-bbl-file-is-not-generated-and-still-malformed-file-bcf-even-if-i-still-use)
- [biber stops during compilation, results in empty bbl file [closed]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299341/biber-stops-during-compilation-results-in-empty-bbl-file)
- [Compiling LaTeX document empties .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179420/compiling-latex-document-empties-bbl-file)
- [Biber produces empty bbl file [closed]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272538/biber-produces-empty-bbl-file)

My System:

- Windows 10x64 2004 19041.388
- pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
- biber version: 2.16
- BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
- biblatex 2020/12/31 v3.16
- Sublime Text 3.2.2 3211
- LaTeXTools st3-4.0.0-alpha.9

MWE:

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
    @Article{Foo,
      author = {Guy, Some},
      title  = {Some Title},
      year   = {2021}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    This is a test.\cite{Foo}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I run

```
pdflatex bib.tex
biber --debug bib
pdflatex bib.tex
pdflatex bib.tex
```

[Output of `bib.blg` on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/dEmbM1xv)

[Output of `bib.log` on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ebp9Gt9B)

Summary:

`biber --cache` don't do the trick

Changing the `TEMP/TMP` user-environment variables don't do the trick either.

Tex-file is located in a non-special-character folder. With second machine it's not working either.

Removing and (re)installing the biber package doesn't did the trick.

Updated the whole TeXLive installation with `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`

```
C:\Temp\mwe>kpsewhich biblatex.sty
c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling as administrator did the trick.

But how can I repair my installation? And why does the error comes up now, but not last week? Didn't update the TeXLive Distro in admin mode.

Comment: I would not want to start compiling documents as admin. When you say `biber --cache` did not work, did you actually delete the directory indicated by `biber --cache` completely or did you just run the command? You really need to delete the cache as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood this, I just ran the command without deleting the folder actually.

And I had to compile as admin, because I needed the paper because of a dead line. I lost 1 day with this "issue". 

Now everything works fine, I don't need to run it as admin any more. Didn't changed anything at all since. (And yes, I tried to turn it off and on again :P)